# problem in Latex

Tags: latex, whitespace, spacing

I have a problem in Latex: if i have:

```
    \begin{enumerate}
\item Alert - Mesaje de avertizare, erori, etc.
\item Form - Permite crearea de ecrane compuse din alte componente, cum ar fi imagini (Image) sau articole derivate din Item (ChoiceGroup, CustomItem, DateField, Gauge, ImageItem, Spacer, StringItem, TextField).
\item List - Ecran pentru selectarea unei op\c tiuni dintr-o mul\c time prestabilit\u a.
\item TextBox - Ecran pentru introducerea unui text.
\end{enumerate}

\bf BIBLIOGRAFIE
\linebreak \linebreak
1.suport\hspace{0.2cm}curs
```

then, i wanna display that BIBLIOGRAFIE after the last item, but with two lines between them. So i have "TextBox - Ecran pentru introducerea unui text.", then two lines, then BIBLIOGRAFIE. how can i write that? with this code, the space between List and TextBox items are very large, and BIBLIOGRAFIE is displayed at the buttom... why? if i use \linebreak after \end{enumerate} i got a compile error
Please help

Thankls!

Comment: please fix your title to something more descriptive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could experiment by either putting it inside one or several [boxes](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Topics#Boxes), either

```
\parbox[pos]{width}{...text...}
```

or

```
\begin{minipage}[pos]{width}...text...\end{minipage}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\vspace` to control vertical spacing.  So in your case since you have too much space, you can pass vspace a negative argument such as `\vspace{-3mm}` and it should move things up for you.

Comment: With \vspace, i got something like here: http://img709.imageshack.us/i/latex.jpg/ 
Without \vspace, the 4. is after 3. But why i have that big space?

\item List - Ecran pentru selectarea unei op\c tiuni dintr-o mul\c time prestabilit\u a.
\item TextBox - Ecran pentru introducerea unui text.
\end{enumerate}
\vspace{-3mm}
\bf BIBLIOGRAFIE
\linebreak \linebreak
1.suport\hspace{0.2cm}curs

so BIBLIOGRAFIE i wanna be displayed after 4. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

I personally hate using any magical numbers in LaTeX; I would prefer

\smallskip
\medskip
\bigskip
\vfill

The linebreak doesn't work, because there is no line to be broken, because writing something after any other code in LaTeX doesn't mean it will appear immediately after that; LaTeX is not like that.

Comment: As a midpoint between explicit lengths and using the various `skip` widths there is always `em`.

Comment: \smallskip does not worked too, see my last comment, there is an uploaded imageshack image... i got too much space between 3. and 4.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to do by hand something that LaTeX will happily do for you.

Instead of using \bf to make a section header, try `\section*{Bibliografie}`.  (The asterisk is to keep the section from being numbered.)  If that header is too big, try `\subsection*{Bibliografie}` or even `\subsubsection*{Bibliografie}`.

Once LaTeX knows that a section header is what you're trying to do, it should insert vertical space for you; you won't need `\linebreak` or anything like it.

Comment: +1: This is the right way to do this.  If you need more control over vertical space, use \titlespacing from the titlesec package to specify the vertical space around the section heading.  CTAN: http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/